# Node.js exited with status 127 when trying to install copilot.vim on NeoVim

Tags: node.js, neovim, github-copilot

I'm trying to install [copilot.vim](https://github.com/github/copilot.vim) on NeoVim.

When I run `:Copilot setup`, I get `Copilot: 'Node.js exited with status 127'`.

I have Node 16 installed, and I tried adding `let g:copilot_node_command = "~/.nodenv/shims/node"` to `init.nim`, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: what the `:checkhealth` say?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the terminal if node is installed properly

```
node -v
```

then install the missing library, in my case it was ICU

```
sudo pacman -S icu
```

that should fix the issue